# GLSL 4.2 - how to retrieve size of image?

Tags: opengl, glsl, image-unit

In GLSL 4.2 one can use the `image2D` datatype with imageLoad and imageStore functions. those functions take `ivec` to determine which pixel to write/read. in order to calculate the proper `ivec`, i need to know the size of the image. But how do I retrieve this?

`textureSize()` seems to work only with samplers, not with images.

How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean - not with images? How do you specify "image" in GLSL?

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko I think he's made it pretty clear, look into the [shader_image_load_store extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt) for more information.

Comment: I expect you just pass it in to the shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. They didn't put in a function to get the image's size, so you'll have to pass it in via a uniform.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [imageSize()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/imageSize.xhtml) in GLSL 4.3. Take a look at GLSL specification from OpenGL.org.

Comment: no idea why this was downvoted. spot on answer after the function was added